# Unobtrusive jQuery autocomplete in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, unobtrusive-javascript

I'm using rails, but doing all my Javascript unobtrusively using jQuery in `application.js`.

Unfortunately, this makes it quite difficult to reference URLs. For example, if I want to give a field autocomplete behavior, I have to hard-code the autocomplete URL in `application.js` since the rails `url_for` isn't available.

Is it possible to make `application.js` use erb? Am I thinking about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could add the url to an attribute on the form or form field, if you don't mind markup that may not pass the validator, and then fetch that attribute with jQuery.

It looks like Rails 3.0 might be going down this route with the javascript helpers using HTML5 custom data attributes: [DHH @ Railsconf 09](http://railsconf.blip.tv/file/2081411/)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible, on current rails versions just call your file `application.js.erb`; on older versions you can either roll your own or grab something like [this](http://embeddedjs.com/).

Comment: Cool! Is this the best practice here? Do you use this method? It sounds good to me, but I'm still nervous I'm working against the grain.

Comment: AFAIK, it made it into rails because so many people were doing it on their own.  It's a very common usage pattern.  One caveat: this is for injecting semi-static things like the routes;  if the contents are going to change within a session, send the javascript in a ajax wrapper instead.

Comment: Actually this doesn't seem to work -- do I have to move the file out of /public/javascripts? If I just rename the file I get a routing error when my browser requests 'application.js'.

Answer (score 2):

Don't do `application.js.erb` , that's not a good practice even if caching is involved. Make you autocomplete endpoint (url from which you are getting the data) the same as your form's action url. In your `application.js` just append `&ac=1` to it and make your controllers understand it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to hardcode it-- just create a single JS function that adds the autocomplete listener, and accepts parameters for the autocomplete, and call that JS function from your template:

*(code simplified for clarity)*

application.js:

```
function add_autocomplete(id, url) {
   $("#" + id).autocomplete(
      source: url  
   );
};
```

application_helper.rb:

```
def add_autocomplete(id, url)
  render :text => "<script> add_autocomplete('#{id}', '#{url}');</script>"
end
```

ERb template:

```
<input id="i_want_autocomplete" />
<%= add_autocomplete("i_want_autocomplete", items_js_path() %>
```